# Yii2: Correct Way to use Jui DatePicker

Tags: php, jquery, date, yii2

My Jui Date Time Picker was working perfectly, I am not sure if I have made any changes in config anywhere, but now the date-picker field is showing the format as if it is asking for time with the date.

This is my code for the date field:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'joining_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(),
                    ['clientOptions' =>[
                        'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                        'showAnim'=>'fold',
                        'changeMonth'=> true,
                        'changeYear'=> true,
                        'autoSize'=>true,
                         'showOn'=> "button",
                         'buttonImage'=> "images/calendar.gif",
                        'htmlOptions'=>[
                        'style'=>'width:80px;',
                        'font-weight'=>'x-small',
                        ],]]) ?>
```

in my Web.php config the relevant code for dates is like

```
'formatter' => [
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
        'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
        'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
        'datetimeFormat'=>'php:d-M-Y H:i:s'
        ],
```

Now I am trying to enter the date I am getting the field like 12/07/2014:
and colon after the field as if I need to add the time part, where from it is coming, I couldn't find.

[date-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrwxM.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I ran into the same problem.

`dateFormat` is no longer the part of `clientOptions` and should be specified like that:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'joining_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
] ?>
```

Alternative in ICU format:

```
'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
```

See official docs for [$dateFormat](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html#$dateFormat-detail) property.

Answer (score -1):

You may help this...
Yii Default date format is taken from configuration (thats the the power of YII::))
under component you have formate date....something how!!!

```
 'formatter'=>[
            'class'=>'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            //'dateFormat' =>'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:d M Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i:s',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i:s',

        ],


use yii\jui\DatePicker; 

<?php echo $form->field($ShipmentTypeForm, 'shipmendate')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
      'options' => ['class' => 'form-control input-sm','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],]); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively use Bootstrap datepicker. You just need to include appropriate  JS file and call something like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'inputName', ['inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form-control datepicker']])->textInput() ?>
```